# How to implement CMD + C and CMD + V in pygame

Tags: python, macos, pygame, copy-paste

I have working example which copies user input running at Windows

```
text=""
if event.key == pygame.K_c and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and not pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
    print("pressed CTRL-C as an event")
    pyperclip.copy(text)
```

but not at mac, I could not find any string representing Mac "command" key in documentation https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html and thus have hard time implementing copying there. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.KMOD_META` represents the command key on macOS. So, your code would look like:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_c and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_META and not pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_ALT:
    print("pressed CMD-C as an event")
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it could be one of the keys there, but I couldn't easily figure out which one.